# parsing through nested arrays with null

Tags: json, jq

When I curl an API and get the following data (sample data):

```
[
  {
    "identifier": "IdNum",
    "name": "TopCatA",
    "subCategories": [
      {
        "categoryId": "19232",
        "identifier": "83434",
        "name": "Mens",
        "sequence": 10,
        "attributes": {
          "PrimaryFaceOutImage": "prod1",
          "PrimaryHoverImage": "model1",
          "categoryLabel": "Mens Clothing & Accessories",
          "viewall": "false"
        },
        "subCategories": [
          {
            "categoryId": "23423423",
            "identifier": "456456456",
            "name": "Shirts",
            "categoryImage": "gfhhfghfg",
            "sequence": 1,
            "attributes": {
              "CategoryGroupType": "features",
              "PrimaryFaceOutImage": "false",
              "viewall": "false"
            }
          },
          {
            "categoryId": "3423423",
            "identifier": "234234234234",
            "name": "Jeans",
            "categoryImage": "sdfadsf-sdfas-asdf-sdfasdf"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "categoryId": "234234234",
        "identifier": "45345",
        "name": "Womens",
        "sequence": 12,
        "attributes": {
          "PrimaryFaceOutImage": "prod1",
          "PrimaryHoverImage": "model1",
          "categoryLabel": "Womens Clothing & Accessories",
          "viewall": "false"
        },
        "subCategories": [
          {
            "categoryId": "23423423",
            "identifier": "456456456",
            "name": "Shirts",
            "categoryImage": "gfhhfghfg",
            "sequence": 1,
            "attributes": {
              "CategoryGroupType": "features",
              "PrimaryFaceOutImage": "false",
              "viewall": "false"
            }
          },
          {
            "categoryId": "3423423",
            "identifier": "234234234234",
            "name": "Jeans",
            "categoryImage": "sdfadsf-sdfas-asdf-sdfasdf"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "categoryId": "23423423",
        "identifier": "SOME_SALE",
        "name": "Sale",
        "sequence": 23,
        "attributes": {
          "PrimaryFaceOutImage": "prod1",
          "PrimaryHoverImage": "model1",
          "viewall": "false"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "identifier": "IdNum",
    "name": "TopCatB",
    "subCategories": [
      {
        "categoryId": "234234",
        "identifier": "45345",
        "name": "Boys",
        "sequence": 43,
        "attributes": {
          "PrimaryFaceOutImage": "prod1",
          "PrimaryHoverImage": "model1",
          "categoryLabel": "Boys Clothing & Accessories",
          "viewall": "false"
        },
        "subCategories": [
          {
            "categoryId": "23423423",
            "identifier": "456456456",
            "name": "Shirts",
            "categoryImage": "gfhhfghfg",
            "sequence": 1,
            "attributes": {
              "CategoryGroupType": "features",
              "viewall": "false"
            }
          },
          {
            "categoryId": "3423423",
            "identifier": "234234234234",
            "name": "Jeans",
            "categoryImage": "sdfadsf-sdfas-asdf-sdfasdf"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "categoryId": "345234",
        "identifier": "345345345",
        "name": "Girls",
        "sequence": 10,
        "attributes": {
          "PrimaryFaceOutImage": "prod1",
          "categoryLabel": "Girls Clothing & Accessories",
          "viewall": "false"
        },
        "subCategories": [
          {
            "categoryId": "23423423",
            "identifier": "456456456",
            "name": "Shirts",
            "categoryImage": "gfhhfghfg",
            "sequence": 1,
            "attributes": {
              "CategoryGroupType": "features",
              "viewall": "false"
            }
          },
          {
            "categoryId": "3423423",
            "identifier": "234234234234",
            "name": "Jeans",
            "categoryImage": "sdfadsf-sdfas-asdf-sdfasdf"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "categoryId": "23423423",
        "identifier": "SOME_SALE",
        "name": "Sale",
        "sequence": 45,
        "attributes": {
          "PrimaryFaceOutImage": "prod1",
          "categoryLabel": "Sale",
          "displaySoldOut": "true",
          "viewall": "false"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to apply a jq filter so as to be left with only the names and values of all the subcategories while maintaining the nested structure and having BOTH TopCatA and TopCatB in the final output.  The issue is that one of the subcategories (sale) doesnt have subcategories like the other ones (Mens, Womens) so I get the `Cannot iterate over null (null)` message.

I have tried a few different jq filters but cant seem to get the nesting to preserve.  The end result I'm looking for is to get something like this:

```
[
    {
      "identifier": "IdNum",
      "name": "TopCatA",
      "subCategories": [
        {
          "name": "Mens",
          "subCategories": [
            {
              "name": "Shirts"
            },
            {
              "name": "Jeans"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Womens",
          "subCategories": [
            {
              "name": "Shirts"
            },
            {
              "name": "Jeans"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Sale"
          "subCategories": NULL
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Here's some of the jq queries I've tried:

`cat ~/temp/testData.json | jq --tab '[.[] | {name: .name, subCat1: [.subCategories[].name], subCat2: [.subCategories[].subCategories[]?.name]} ]'` <--not useful as nesting is lost

I am trying to accomplish this via only filters and pipes as I am not too strong with doing selects in jq.

Comment: There are answers to similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531722/jq-streaming-filter-nested-list-and-retain-global-structure

Comment: I saw that question and the accepted answer was to use tempfiles and select statements.  My question is whether I can avoid that and use nothing but pipes and filters and no select statements.

Comment: And if the answer is that I DO have to use some combination of selects and tempfiles, then I may have to ask a new question "How do I build a jq query with selects and tempfiles" ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `[]` instead of `null` doesn't bother you:

```
map(.subCategories |=
  map({name, subCategories: (.subCategories // [] |
    map({name}))}))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Ra6iOY47qf)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried using `|=` but wasnt too familiar with how it worked.  Any chance you can explain a little how this works?

Comment: @JuanD `|=` is the update operator. Take this for example: `.key |= filter`; in `filter` expression, `.` is `.key`, and `.key`'s value is updated with `filter`'s result. Everything else in above query is pretty trivial, just refer to the manual.

Comment: Wow nice, simple and elegant, especially compared to what I was currently trying to do with delpaths. Jq is amazing and really worth learning.

Comment: @rolf82 don't hesitate to post your solution, if it works I'll definitely upvote